# racket/gui: sleep without freezing gui

Tags: user-interface, racket, sleep

I'm writing a unit test and I want to:

1. open a frame
2. wait a few seconds
3. close the frame

Here's the code I tried:

```
#lang racket/base
(require plot racket/class)

(define f
  (plot3d-frame (surface3d (λ (x y) (* (cos x) (sin y))) -3.0 3.0 -3.0 3.0)))
(send f show #true)
(sleep 10)
(send f show #false)
```

Running this opens a blank frame, waits 10 seconds, and closes the frame. The plot never appears. I guess this is because `sleep` puts the whole thread, including the [eventspace](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/windowing-overview.html#%28part._eventspaceinfo%29), to sleep.

Is there a way to make my code sleep without making the GUI to sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [`sleep/yield`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/Windowing_Functions.html#%28def._%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._sleep%2Fyield%29%29)

```
#lang racket/base
(require plot racket/class racket/gui/base)

(define f
  (plot3d-frame (surface3d (λ (x y) (* (cos x) (sin y))) -3.0 3.0 -3.0 3.0)))
(send f show #true)
(sleep/yield 10)
(send f show #false)
;; "It works every time!"
```